The hostname command outputs two IP addresses when one is expected
# hostname --help | grep ip
    -i, --ip-address       addresses for the host name
    -I, --all-ip-addresses all addresses for the host

According to the above, -i should output just one IP address, while -I should output all. In my case, it works the other way around.
# hostname -i
127.0.1.1 123.123.123.123

# hostname -I
123.123.123.123

Why is that?
Here's my /etc/hosts file in case it matters:
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost       ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       tmp-1   tmp-1

123.123.123.123 tmp-1

(Where 123.123.123.123 is my real actual IP v4 address.)

Since you checked the help text, did you also check the manpage?

You're right, I didn't. Please post this as an answer so I can accept.

The hostname(1) manpage describes these options in full, which should clarify the confusion:

-i, --ip-address
Display the network address(es) of the host name. Note that this works only if the host name can be resolved. Avoid using this option; use hostname --all-ip-addresses instead.
-I, --all-ip-addresses
Display all network addresses of the host. This option enumerates all configured addresses on all network interfaces. The loopback interface and IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted. Contrary to option -i, this option does not depend on name resolution. Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.

(In any case, the help text for -i says "addresses",  so multiple addresses can be expected there.)

Thank you for clarifying!

@ᴍᴇʜᴏᴠ The when using -i, the loopback address is displayed only because you added the hostname to the address in /etc/hosts. If you kept only localhost* as the name for 127.0.0.1 and ::1 you would not see them in the output.

@doneal24 Ah, makes sense, thank you. The server was configured like that by my provider, but at least now I understand where 127.0.0.1 in the output comes from
